# Getting a list of merged commits through GitHub REST api v3

Tags: git, api, rest, github

Given a git repository hosted on GitHub, how can I use the GitHub REST API v3 to give me a list of SHA hashes corresponding to merges on the master branch of that repository, that is, the equivalent of:

```
 git log --merges
```

on the command line ?

I looked at the online documentation for the [REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits), but I could not find anything that explicitly describes what I need.

I see that I can list commits, for example https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits (this is not the actual repository I'm working on, but just an example).

I thought using `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/merges` would be the answer, but that returns a 'not found' response for my repository, and the same for the example one above (http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/merges).

Our merges don't always go through Pull Requests, so searching for merged Pull Requests may not give the complete picture. But this seems to work (eg https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls?state=closed) and will be the alternative option.

Comment: It seems the `/repos/:owner/:repo/merges` entrypoint has a different purpose, namely, triggering a merge (after a `POST` request): https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/merging/

Comment: Otherwise a possible idea (maybe less efficient than, e.g., doing a shallow clone and a local git command?) might consist in browsing the list of commits from the branch `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits` and extracting the commits who have 2+ parents?

Comment: Thanks. the original script I have actually makes use of command-line git calls and works, but my team prefer a switch to the GitHub api.